# Django upload multiple images at once

Tags: python, angularjs, json, django

I would like to upload multiple images to a django backend via JSON. 
My frontend post looks somethings like this (images is an array of Base64 encoded images):

```
return $http.post('/api/v1/images/', {
    project: project,
    images: images
  });
```

My django model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

My serializer:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
project = ProjectSerializer(read_only=True, required=False)
image = Base64ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    many = kwargs.pop('many', True)
    super(ImageSerializer, self).__init__(many=many, *args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    model = Image
    fields = ('id', 'project', 'image')
    read_only_fields = ('id')
```

My view:

```
class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Image.objects.order_by('-image')
serializer_class = ImageSerializer

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    currentProject = Project.objects.all().get(name = self.request.data['project'])
    instance = serializer.save(project = currentProject)
    return super(ImageViewSet, self).perform_create(serializer)
```

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? Have you received any errors?

Comment: Exactly, I always get a Bad Request Exception...